# MVC 5 - Checkbox and Conditional CSS based on value of property on viewmodel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial MVC 5 view that passes in a view model.  On the viewModel there's an "IsActive" property... Based on this property, I would like to add or remove the @disabled = "disabled" html attribute for text inputs view.  I have it working after the initial load with JQuery, but can't seem to conditionally apply it on init.

**ViewModel**

```
  public class InfoViewModel
  {
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string HouseholdName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

}
```

**Partial View**

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseholdName, new {@class = "control-label"}):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HouseholdName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseholdName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label" }):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

**CheckBox**

```
 <div class="controls">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </label>
 </div>
```

**JQuery that applies CSS if checkbox is checked/unchecked**

```
 activeChanged: function(e) {

        //Checkbox ID
    if ($("#InfoViewModel_IsActive").is(':unchecked')) {

        //Text inputs** 
        $("#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName").prop("readonly", true);
        $('#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName').css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").prop("readonly", true);
        $('#InfoViewModel_LastName').css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');


    } else {
        $("#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName").prop("readonly", false);
        $('#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName').css('background-color', '#FFF');

        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").css('background-color', '#FFF');



    }
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what works and what doesn't from your question - does the client-side editing work (toggling the readonly based on the checking/unchecking of the checkbox with the jQuery you posted) but the initial load of the page doesn't reflect the IsActive setting by setting the initial disabled attributes of your inputs?

Comment: You can use `@{ var attributes = Model.IsActive ? (object)new { @class = "someClass", readonly = "readonly" } : (object)new { @class = "anotherClass"}); }` and then `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HouseholdName, attributes)` (note it better to use class names rather than inline styles)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem in many ways, for example:

JavaScript

```
activeChanged: function(e) {
    //Checkbox ID
    if ($("#InfoViewModel_IsActive").is(':unchecked')) {
        activeOrDesactiveProperties(false);
    } else {
        activeOrDesactiveProperties(true);
    }
},

function activeOrDesactiveProperties(isActive) {
    if (!isActive) {
        //Text inputs** 
        $("#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName").prop("readonly", true);
        $('#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName').css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").prop("readonly", true);
        $('#InfoViewModel_LastName').css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
    } else {
        $("#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName").prop("readonly", false);
        $('#InfoViewModel_HouseholdName').css('background-color', '#FFF');

        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#InfoViewModel_LastName").css('background-color', '#FFF');
    }
}
```

In your view adds this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    activeOrDesactiveProperties(@this.Model.IsActive);
</script>
```